# How do you overload python class method based on Enum type

Tags: python, enums, overloading, metaclass

I am trying to create a python method for a class which uses overload typing decorator. I want the method to be overloaded based on the Enum type being passed. For example,

```
class GetPortType(enum.Enum):
    DIFF_1: "Diff1"
    DIFF_2: "Diff2"
    SAME_1: "Same1"
    SAME_2: "Same2"

class Port:
...
    @typing.overload
    def get_port_on_type(self, type: GetPortType.DIFF_1, num: int, skip: Optional[List]):
        statement1
        statement2
        return [values]

    @typing.overload
    def get_port_on_type(self, type: GetPortType.DIFF_2, num: int, skip: Optional[List]):
        statement3
        statement4
        return [values]

    @typing.overload
    def get_port_on_type(self, type: GetPortType.SAME_1, num: int, skip: Optional[List]):
        statement1
        statement3
        return [values]

    @typing.overload
    def get_port_on_type(self, type: GetPortType.SAME_2, num: int, skip: Optional[List]):
        statement2
        statement4
        return [values]
```

How do I achieve this? Should I create a "def __ new __(self, value):" method for the Enum and return type for all these cases?

EDIT: I was wondering if there was something we could do with Metaclass and like value return type maybe? Which could be a property of this metaclass?

```
@property
def type(self):
    return type(self.value)

""" changing the type annotation """
type: GetPortType.SAME_2.type
```

Comment: Have you tried `typing.Literal`.  The type of the last one would be `Literal[GetPortType.SAME_2]`, for example.

Comment: I don't think you understand, `typing.overload` does not let you actually use method overloading. It is merely for *type annotations*.

Comment: `type: GetPortType.DIFF_2` **that is not a type**!

Comment: @FrankYellin look closely though, the OP seems to think that you can have *different implementations* based on the overloaded signatures.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  Oops.  I thought they were just asking a typing question.  Sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I was wondering if there was something we could do with Metaclass and maybe have a type property which I can then call in the type annotation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you've misunderstood what `typing.overload` does. It *does not* let you define different versions of your code that get run in different situations. Rather, it's used for type hinting, to indicate that several combinations of types are supported by *a single* implementation. None of the overload definitions of the function will ever be run, they *only* add better type hinting to the real version of the function that comes later.

Here's an example [given in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload):

```
@overload
def process(response: None) -> None:
    ...
@overload
def process(response: int) -> tuple[int, str]:
    ...
@overload
def process(response: bytes) -> str:
    ...
def process(response):
    <actual implementation>
```

Note that the `...` elipsis literal is something you might actually put in this code, it's not standing in for something only left out for the documentation. There's no body needed in those `@overload` decorated functions, since they never run. The `...` literal seems to have emerged among type-hinting aficionados as a preferred body for function stubs, rather than `pass` (which at least used to be the preferred "do nothing" body for a function).

If you actually need a decorator that will run a different version of a function depending on an argument's type, you might be able to use [`functools.singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch). But it *only* dispatches on actual types, not literal values like you're wanting (e.g. specific instances of an `Enum`).

The simple solution to your problem is just to write a set of `if`/`elif`/`else` blocks to separate out the calls once you're inside the function:

```
def get_port_on_type(self, type: GetPortType, num: int, skip: Optional[List]):
    if type == GetPortType.DIFF_1:
        do_stuff_1()
    elif type == GetPortType.DIFF_2:
        do_stuff_2()
    elif type == GetPortType.SAME_1:
        do_stuff_3()
    else: # type == GetPortType.SAME_2:
        do_stuff_4()
```

Starting in Python 3.10, you can use the new [`match` and `case` statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-match-statement) to do essentially the same thing as the chain of `if`/`elif`/`else` code above, with a very slightly nicer syntax, but I'm still using 3.9 and I don't feel confident in writing an example for you that I can't test (see [PEP 636](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636) for a tutorial on the new statement types).